# Accessibility If the option element contains more than twenty-five (25) select children flag as a violation

Tags: accessibility

for e.g. I have calendar dates drop down which has 31 numeric values listed.
In accessibility testing, its shows violation.

I have found alternative solution `<optgroup label="">`, but it's not practically possible for this scenario. 
Current Scenario

```
<select class="" name="day" data-componentid="" id="">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">30</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Which tool you are using for this testing?

Comment: AMP tool for Firefox - SSB BART Group

Comment: Please add some more information about the error you are receiving.

Comment: Which Accessibility standards are you testing to?

Comment: Form-> Ensure option elements in large lists are grouped -> If the option element contains more than twenty-five (25) select children flag as a violation. Accessibility standards AA 2.0

Comment: This is good example of an accessibility testing tool causing confusion because WCAG does not even say that

Comment: Devang, Splatz answer and comments are right on the spot, this is a case where some tool throws a quite dubious result. Moreover, your test results are OPPOSED to WCAG, so well, no much more to say

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea what your tool is unhappy about but there are **no** accessibility issues with drop-down fields containing 31 items, even when you use the value attribute.

I suspect you are misunderstanding one of the WCAG2.0 requirements, e.g. Technique H85 for Success Criterion 1.3.1 (Info and Relationships) https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H85.html

As you can see from this technique, it is only saying ***if*** the data in your drop-down can be semantically grouped, use the optgroup element to create those groups because accessible readers have features to allow users to skim the groups.

So this is not even applicable to your situation, where there are no logical groupings, i.e. they are just sequential numbers from 1 to 31.

This is why accessibly testing tools are to be used with a lot of caution. They can only report on limited things and you need to have good accessibility knowledge to interpret their results.

From a usability perspective, selecting a number from 1 to 31 using a drop-down field is not very usable nor efficient for anybody (click to expand drop-down, scroll down list to find the number and click again).

This is why accessibility experts often say making something accessible improves usability, so consider using a different approach to selecting a date.

Comment: very nice and well explained answer

Comment: Great answer. One idea would be to allow users to either type in a date or pick from the list.